# I'm getting an error in this code, discord.py, and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: discord.py

I'm getting the below error with this code, and I'm not sure why it doesn't detect an id with guilds, it works with another command but not this with a on_ready triggering it

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        ctx = commands.Context
        await self.changena(ctx)
    async def changena(self, ctx):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        nps[ctx.guild.id] = None
        nastates[ctx.guild.id] = 1
nps[ctx.guild.id] = None
AttributeError: 'cached_property' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: You can't create your own context, there is no guild present in there so you can't get its id... Also, you forgot brackets `()` when creating the Context so you're only referring to the class, not an actual instance of it.

Comment: putting @commands.command() doesn't change anything

Comment: Where did you put the command decorator? Above the event or above the changena function?

Comment: each guild that the bot is in should have now playing song to None, and the nastates is for afk command

Comment: above the command it's self

Comment: this is the command
```async def changena(self, ctx):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        nps[ctx.guild.id] = None
        nastates[ctx.guild.id] = 1```

Comment: Then you're still trying to call it from the `on_ready` event, which is still gonna cause the same error. Making `changena` a command isn't gonna fix that, just don't call it from the event at all.

Comment: I'm trying to make it where nastates[ctx.guild.id] = 1 and nps[ctx.guild.id] = None at start up of the bot, basically making the afk mode default to disabled, if i don't put nps to none it gives me a KeyError: then the id of the guild it's currently in, when i type the play command, i'm using a test bot so it's only in one guild

Comment: Uhu, but there is no `Guild` on startup of the bot, what is "the guild" that you're setting it for? `ctx.guild` refers to the guild that invoked the command, but an on_ready event doesn't get fired from a Guild at all so there is none... What guild are you expecting to be in there?

Comment: If you don't want a `KeyError` then first check if the key already exists before trying to access it, otherwise give it a default value first.

Comment: i'm trying to make nps = none and nastates = 1 for all guilds, upon start up of the bot by using wait_until_ready but that doesn't work

Comment: If you want to do it for all guilds then use a `for-loop` that loops over all the guilds of the bot. How would all guilds ever be in a `Context()` that you create on the spot?

Comment: i dont know how to make a for loop

Comment: That's basic python, you can look that up on the internet very easily and find it in a few seconds. I won't explain that in here.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> i'm trying to make nps = none and nastates = 1 for all guilds

Either loop over all guilds that your bot is in ([`Client.guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=guilds#discord.ext.commands.Bot.guilds)), or check if they exist before accessing them. The first option explains itself, so I'll only explain the second one.

```py
# Both are empty at first
nps = {}
nastates = {}

...
# Wherever you access them, check if they exist first
if guild_id not in nps:
    # If they don't exist, give them a default value
    nps[guild_id] = None
    nastates[guild_id] = 1

# You can now use
nps[guild_id]
# Without getting a KeyError
```

Why do you get your initial error?

First of all, **never** make your own `Context`. Second, you only passed a reference to the `class`, you didn't make an instance of it. To create a new instance, you need to put brackets `()` after it. `Context()`. You're only referencing the attribute itself, it doesn't have a value.

Lastly, when creating an empty Context the guild won't exist so you can't access that field. Hence, you can't get the `id` either because there is no guild in the first place.